# rewind one step back in mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

this is the values in the `$result`

- id name
- 1 a
- 2 b
- 2 c
- 2 d
- 3 e

..

I'm creating a loop function using mysql_fetch_array()

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $temp_id = $row['id'];

    while($temp_id == $row['id']) {
         if($temp_id == $row['id']) {
              mysql_fetch_array($result);
         }
         $temp_id = $row['id'];
         echo $row['name'].",";

    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

this works but the problem is, the mysql_fetch_array jumps on one of the values during the transition of the id's..

I want the values of this to be like these

```
a
b,c,d
e
```

my question is, is there a simple rewind function that will step only once in the rows?
I have searched about the `mysql_data_seek()` but I think this would require additional control variables like `$i` to locate the address..

thanks.. any suggestions and function samples will be very great!

Comment: Why you need to compare your $temp_id == $row['id'] inside your while statement? Your while statement shows that the sql will execute just only $temp_id == $row['id'] and you compare with the same execution

Comment: What do you want to retrieve?

Comment: well yeah, you're right.. as of now, I've removed that already, but still, the value jumps.. my guess is that mysql_fetch_array() is declared twice..then the rows jumps twice.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, I've already edited my question, that's what I want to display...

Comment: You want to print first row on the first row, others without last at the second row and last row at the 3rd row?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, uh, I want to print the names in each line according to their id..

Comment: I answered on your question. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one loop with `mysql_fetch_array` first to create an array of the rows.  Then, iterate over the rows themselves.

Based on the update to your question it seems like you would want to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in the query, but you can still do it in PHP:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!isset($rows[$row['id']]) {
        $rows[$row['id'] = array();
    }
    $rows[$row['id']][] = $row['name'];
}
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo implode(',', $row) . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $temp[$row['id']][] = $row['name'];
}
foreach($temp as $row) {
    echo implode(',', $row) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: whoah, I think this is the better code! Thanks! but I think I'll give my vote to Explosion Pills.. anyway, thanks for answering!!